# How do I install pyQt on MacOs, Python 3.5.1?

Tags: qt, pyqt

I already tried installing it with 'brew install pyqt' and the command did it's thing, but I still get an importing error.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to follow this guide:
https://gist.github.com/guillaumevincent/10983814